# Joi - allow({}) is not working when object has required fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

With Joi, I want to make an empty object (object with no own properties) as valid or an object with certain structure as valid. But I am not sure how to do it. The following was my attempt and it was not working. Can anyone give me alternate suggestions?

```
joi.validate({}, joi.object({ 
    a: joi.string().required(),
    b: joi.string().required(),
}).optional().allow({}));
```

The above code fails, if I send in an empty object. But see, I clearly mentioned it in `.allow()`

So I want to write a joi schema to accept the following data structures as valid,

```
{}

 Or

{ a: 'some-string', b: 'some-string' }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might solve your problem.

```
const obj = {};
const length = Object.keys(obj).length;

const { error: joiError, value: joiValue } = length > 0 ? joiSchema.validate(obj) : true;

joiSchema = Joi.object().keys({
    a: joi.string().required(),
    b: joi.string().required(),
});
```